# Move photoshop viewport 1 pixel at a time

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I can move a photoshop layer 1px at a time, however I need to be able to move the viewport (so all layers move together).

I need to so I can align with a browser window behind it (photoshop is transparent).

At the moment, I have to use the scrollbar however it's a pain to get it to align pixel perfect (near impossible). If I need to scroll both I have to align all again (would be ok if I can move the view 1 pixel at a time).

Thank you

Comment: Hi cassidy1991, welcome to GDSE. I assume [this](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/80939/52050) is you? You should refrain from re-asking the same question, you can always edit your original with any new details. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help].

Comment: I didn't know how to edit my original question sorry.

Comment: Can't you just take a screenshot of the browser window and then lay that over the top in Photoshop?

Comment: Not really, as I am changing the browser (making the webpage from the psd) so I would then have to keep taking a screenshot every change

Comment: If it's all within one document, I also don't see why you wouldn't be able to have a browser screenshot in the psd? I didn't really understand what you were saying in your comment there. What do you mean you are changing the browser?

Comment: I have the psd as the design, I need to turn that into html (webpage). while doing so I need the psd to be aligned to the webpage so I can change the webpage (let say some text in a box, I change it in html until it matches the psd...). Taking screenshot of the webpage every time I change something is not what I am looking for as it would take more time. Is there no way to nudge the viewport 1 pixel at a time (like you can do with layers)? Is there anything I can download that could do that?

Comment: It sounds like nudging the entire Photoshop program window would do the trick, right?

[ 
+ Alt-Tab or Click On the Window
+ Press "Alt & Space"
+ Press "M"
+ Use your arrow keys to move the Window
+ Press Enter to exit
 ]

Comment: Paul Shryock yes! that will work, I have to hold ctrl when using the arrow keys to make windows move it 1 pixel but this is what I wanted! Thanks.

Comment: @PaulShryock it sounds like you've got the right answer. Would you mind putting it below as an answer so cassidy1991 can accept it?

Comment: There is a better alternative approach. You can lay out the result of the PSD as a background for your web page. Also the screen capture idea is not as bad as it sounds if you capture it by script, then you can allways capture to a linked file which updates on change. Essentially using photoshop as a limited browser (no extra actions on your part)

Comment: I think Paul's suggestion is best (for me) as I don't need any scripts or to save as a image and place in the webpage. His way allows me to quickly move photoshop 1 pixel. I will accept Paul's once he has put as an answer.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you gotta have the Photoshop document on top of the website in progress? Because there are tools meant specifically for what you are doing, minus the Photoshop. One of them would be a browser plugin called [Perfect Pixel](http://welldonecode.com/perfectpixel).  I don't know any windows applications, but I know of two mac apps: [Uber Layer](http://twelvetwenty.nl) and [Glue Print](http://glueprintapp.com). Perfect Pixel should be enough, but I figured that the mac apps may have some added functionality just in the fact that they can be used with any application.

Comment: @joojaa Sorry I was waiting for Paul to submit the answer however it looked as if he was not going to post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a Windows machine you can try this little aplication:

http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/

I use it to make a quick resampling of browser windows to simulate diferent resolutions, but you can quicly make a custom position of the aplication window. (Top and Left boxes)

[image]

---

And another option is what Paul Shryock comented (on windows) Alt+Space bar and choose Move.

If you use the keyboard it will move 10px but if you use the Ctrl key and the arrows will move 1px.

Answer (score 0):

Nudge the entire Photoshop program window:

- Alt-Tab or Click On the Window
- Press "Alt & Space"
- Press "M"
- Hold CTRL and use your arrow keys to move the Window
- Press Enter to exit